# Catch error message from stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

how catch error message etc "Error converting data type varchar to datetime"

and this error put in Select output

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

     begin try 
        UPDATE projects
        SET 
            projectUser = @projectUser,
            projectStartDate = @projectStartDate
        where projectId = @projectId
        SELECT 'OK'
     end try

     begin catch
        SELECT 'ERROR - msg error'
     end catch    

    COMMIT

END
```

I don't need ==> https://postimg.org/image/u8mohtl9b/

Any solution?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also show example data that is causing the code to fail.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Looks like product specific code.)

Comment: Instead of worrying about how to catch the error message, why don't you fix it. The most likely way I can see that you could raise this error is if `@projectStartDate` is being passed to the procedure/query as a varchar. Simply change the datatypes of the parameters to match the data types of the columns and you have solved your problem. If you insist on using incorrect data types and handling the error, then you can use [`ERROR_MESSAGE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx) to capture it.

Comment: @jarlh SQL 2012

Comment: I want result as https://postimg.org/image/lkgzwmq4f/

Comment: There is an answer that tells you how to extract information about the error, I have also given you a link to Books Online for the function that extracts the exact message (`ERROR_MESSAGE()`, and I have told you how to fix the actual problem so you get no error, Short of actually writing your full procedure I am not sure what more you are after?

Comment: @GarethD "Error converting data type varchar to datetime" is only sample I know how fix that with change datatype!  But for any other error I need resault as  postimg.org/image/lkgzwmq4f  where is all OK i want message "Update successfuly"... This message from storedprocedure I display in aplication! Now when is all OK I get message but for other I don't have any information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is that the error is not occuring in the procedure, it is occuring when calling the procedure. In a simple example, create the following procedure:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.ErrorCatchTest', 'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.ErrorCatchTest;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ErrorCatchTest @int INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @T TABLE (I INT);
        INSERT @T (I) VALUES (5.0 / @int);

        SELECT 'OK';
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT CONCAT('Error_Message: ', ERROR_MESSAGE());
    END CATCH
END;
```

If I pass a valid `INT` to the procedure:

```
EXECUTE dbo.ErrorCatchTest @int = 1;
```

The I get `OK` as required.

[image]

If I a pass `0` to force an error:

```
EXECUTE dbo.ErrorCatchTest @int = 0;
```

[image]

You get the error message as required, but if I try an pass an invalid integer:

```
EXECUTE dbo.ErrorCatchTest @int = 'Not a number';
```

[image]

Then I get the error message, because the error is not within the proceudure, but while doing an implicit convert on the parameters.

The way around this is to call the procedure within a try/catch block:

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXECUTE dbo.ErrorCatchTest @int = 'Not a number';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT CONCAT('Error_Message: ', ERROR_MESSAGE()); 
END CATCH
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can select the error message like below...

```
Begin Catch     
      SELECT 'Error_Message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' Error_Line: ' + ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorMessage    
End Catch
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only error message,use the below script.

```
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT 'Error_Message :'+ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

sample output :

[image]

Comment: I don't know is it possible get ==> https://postimg.org/image/5wsxjfuy5/